# Как сгруппировать рядом "стоящие" элементы?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У Rails есть метод `group_by`, который, например, может сгруппировать все записи по дате.

Я хочу добиться немного иного результата.

Все записи в таблице по умолчанию сортируются по полю `created_at`. Также в таблице есть поле `option`, в котором хранится какое-то `string` значение.

Например, отсортированная таблица выглядит так:

```
ID  |   Option
1       test1
2       test2
3       test2
4       test1
5       test1
6       test1
7       test2
8       test1
9       test3
```

Мне нужно получить следующие группы:

```
test1: 1
test2: 2, 3
test1: 4, 5, 6
test2: 7
test1: 8
test3: 9
```

То есть идет группирование рядом "стоящих" элементов.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать подобное.

Comment: а обычным циклом сжать не хотите? Именно стандартный метод нужен?

Comment: @pavel необязательно. Мне нужно хоть какое-то адекватное решение, либо подсказка. Я просто на текущий момент вообще не представляю как это реализовать. Так что если вы знаете как это реализовать циклом, то буду рад узреть это решение :)

Comment: я не знаю как сделать именно на рельсах. В псевдокоде как-то так `array {key; array {int} }res; var prev_key = null; var pos = 0; for (int i=0;i < length;i++) if (get_key(i) != prev_key) prev_key = get_key(i), res[++pos].key = prev_key; res[pos].val += get_value(i)`.

Comment: @pavel так и не понял как это реализовать на Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в качестве "ключа", выступают повторяющиеся элементы, что означает, что хэшом воспользоваться не получится, так как у него ключи уникальные. Предложенные вариант с группировкой средствами базы данных не плохо, однако, в разных базах данных функция группировки называется по-разному, в PostgreSQL — это `ARRAY_AGG()`, в MySQL — это `GROUP_CONCAT()`. В принципе подход здравый и рабочий.

Однако, если при решении задачи ориентировался чисто на Ruby, можно избежать зависимости от реализации группирующей функции в базе данных. Например, можно воспользоваться методом `slice_when` из модуля `Enumerable`, который выполняет агрегацию коллекции, по заданным пользователем правилам. В данном случае, в качестве правила группировки может служить неравенство текущего значения Option предыдущему.

Вероятно вам не составит труда представить исходную коллекцию в виде массива массивов

```
h = [
  ['test1', 1],
  ['test2', 2],
  ['test2', 3],
  ['test1', 4],
  ['test1', 5],
  ['test1', 6],
  ['test2', 7],
  ['test1', 8],
  ['test3', 9]
]
```

Тогда решение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
results = h.slice_when { |b, a| b.first != a.first }.map do |m|
  [m.first.first, m.reduce([]) { |m, o| m << o.last }]
end
```

В результате получается следующий массив массивов

```
[
  ["test1", [1]],
  ["test2", [2, 3]],
  ["test1", [4, 5, 6]],
  ["test2", [7]],
  ["test1", [8]],
  ["test3", [9]]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то наподобие?

```
Order.select("Option, ARRAY_AGG(ID) as Ids").group("Option")
```

Это для Postgres.

В общем, должно получиться SQL-выражение

```
SELECT Option, ARRAY_AGG(ID) AS Ids FROM Orders GROUP BY Option;
```

Comment: Ваш пример не помог

Comment: Это возможно, я в ActiveRecord давно не работал, попробуйте выполнить именно SQL-выражение (есть такая ручка в AR), это точно работает в Postgres, проверял.